# Error with discord bot on sending message

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting this strange error on adding this sending message with the discord Bot. I was following the Scratch Tutorial & everything went fine except this when I try to send a message on bot active.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  client.user.setActivity('You', {type: 'WATCHING'});

  var mainChannel = client.channels.get('51549559XXXX')
  mainChannel.send("Hello, world!")
});

client.on('message', (received) => {
 if (received.author == client.user) {
    return
}
    received.channel.send("You: " + received.content);
});  

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Result:-

`(node:8480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at C:\Users\Deepanshu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
    at C:\Users\Deepanshu\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
(node:8480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:8480) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:8480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at C:\Users\Deepanshu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
    at C:\Users\Deepanshu\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
(node:8480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied your code and tried it, and it works perfectly fine. So the problem must be with some of your permissions, as shown by the error. Maybe the mainChannel that you're trying to send a message doesn't allow messages to be sent from the bot.